# Why is node running and how was it started?

Tags: debian, node.js

On Debian11/KDE I see that node is running and accessing the Internet but I didn't start it.

How can I find out how it got started to see why it's running and prevent that? `ps -p {pid} -lf` doesn't show useful information. If it autostarts or started after some upgrade, I'd like to see and prevent that.

Comment: Maybe systemd is running a service which runs node. First try getting the PID number of the proccess `node` and try one of these commands: `ps -o 'pid,ppid,args,unit' pid_node_proccess` or `systemctl status pid_node_proccess`

Comment: The first command just shows that unit that started it was `user@1000.service`; the 2nd one has it beneath the branch `app-konsole-{id}.scope` (what does that mean?) and it seems like what's running is `npm/node_modules/update-notifier/check.js {"pkg":{"name":"npm","version":"6.14.16"}}`

Comment: About the first one means the node command is part of the user `1000` session (your current user). About the second one I'm not really sure but it seems that the konsole/terminal is running the node js application. Maybe an installation/update create the 'startup' configuration for this node js app. Just try checking the file `npm/node_modules/update-notifier/check.js` and see all is OK (check it's not a type of malware)